Subaru clutch pedal in/down/out causes quiet groaning
2013 Subaru Impreza (base, so I think the 2.2 engine). 60k miles, so clearly infrequently driven, but it gets a good hour on the highway every month, on average. (It’s not our principal car.) I know I’m behind on this, but have done nothing (except 5k oil changes) with the fluids, which I do understand is negligent and behind schedule.
Now that the radio is broken :( I’ve noticed that anytime I’m pressing the clutch pedal, it emits a low groan from the engine compartment. I don’t think this is linkages, as it continually groans when the pedal is on the floor.
I’ve seen mention of throw-out bearings, and kind of understand where that might go. I’ve read about clutch cylinders and due to my lack of knowledge, I’m a little baffled about that possibility. I will say that the clutch pedal feels normal: no softness, always returns properly.
Two other, older things about this transmission that may or may not be relevant. If we don’t cram it hard into 3rd, it will very occasionally fall out and create a terrible buzz of misaligned gears. Hasn’t happened in months, though, so maybe we’re getting better at a firm set. (For what it’s worth, both drivers have done stick for almost 40 years, which I know isn’t a qualification so much as a statement of familiarity. I claim that we’re above average, haha. I’ve passed 3 driving tests with sticks.)
The other thing that is ongoing is the downshift from 5 to 4 will grind unless we aggressively match revs.
So, what’s my path forward? Do all the fluids I’ve been neglecting? New throw out bearing and clutch? Look at the clutch cylinders? Does this sound like something that’ll go catastrophically wrong someday or might it gradually get to a point where it’ll still work but be more obviously in need of repair?
Whew! That was a lot. Appreciate any help.

Are you the original owner of the vehicle? How has it been driven (ie: spirited, easy, etc) since you've owned it? How "loud" is the groaning noise? Does it only happen when the pedal is all the way to the floor, or anywhere in the pedal stroke?

Original owner. Generally easy driving, except the occasional ‘let er rip on country roads’. The groaning isn’t loud, and happens everywhere in the pedal stroke.

You might want to try changing out the fluid in your transmission. I don't know what the change interval is or if there even is one, but it might make things better. If there is a synthetic spec for your transmission, I'd use that. If that does nothing, you are either looking at a throwout bearing (best scenario) or a bad bearing inside the transmission.
